# How to display multiple fields value with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have this JSON :

```
{
  "connections": [
    {
      "resourceName": "user_1",
      "etag": "etag_value_1",
      "emailAddresses": [
        {
          "metadata": {
            "primary": true,
            "source": {
              "type": "CONTACT",
              "id": "id_1"
            }
          },
          "value": "email_1",
          "type": "home"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "resourceName": "user_2",
      "etag": "etag_value_2",
      "emailAddresses": [
        {
          "metadata": {
            "primary": true,
            "source": {
              "type": "CONTACT",
              "id": "id_2"
            }
          },
          "value": "email_2",
          "type": "home"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I would like to display something like this :

```
{
  "resourceName": "user_1",
  "etag": "etag_value_1",
  "value": "email_1"
}
```

I'm playing with something like this but does not work :

```
jq '.connections[].emailAddresses[] | {.resourceName, .etag, .value}' test.json
```

How can I do that with JQ binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path expression is wrong, the fields `resourceName` and `etag` are present in the top level path inside array of `connections`, and the `value` field is inside the `emailAddresses` array.

Since you are forming an object, wrap the fields over `{..}`

```
.connections[] | { resourceName, etag } + ( .emailAddresses[] | { value } )
```

If you are looking for the first object alone, do `.connections[0]` or as in above for all the objects.